# VBA How to copy the content of a cell without .Select

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2003

I am writing a method that can take the `Target` and paste the cell exactly to another cell. The cell is a shipping label with some fancy formatting. Is there a way I can do it?

Originally I have this:

```
Worksheets("Label").Range("A1").Value = Worksheets("Get Address").Range("A28").Value
```

It worked for the plain text. However I lost the styling I created, they are different because after the first line, the style is different:

> [image]

I also tried to use Macro Recorder and I got a solution using `.Select`, and I [read this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/excel-macro-avoiding-using-select/10718179#10718179) not to use it whenever possible. What can I do?

```
' Created by the Macro Recorder
Range("A28:A33").Select
Range("A33").Activate
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Label").Select
Range("A1").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
```

Comment: Your code can be re-writtenn in a single line `Range("A33").Copy Sheets("Label").Range("A1")`

Comment: +1 for the awesome address example

Answer (score 24, accepted):

```
Worksheets("Get Address").Range("A33").Copy _
       Destination := Worksheets("Label").Range("A1")
```

Answer (score 7):

to copy and paste values only then use following

```
Worksheets("Label").Range("A1").value = _
   Worksheets("Get Address").Range("A33").value
```

this statement will not use clip board

Answer (score 0):

You can loop thru each cell of the range to copy and set each cell's value, comment, etc in the target destination.
Here's an example.

```
Sub CopySpecial(p_RangeFrom As String, p_OffsetRow As Integer, p_OffsetColumn As Integer)

    Dim l_Row As Integer
    Dim l_Column As Integer
    Dim thisCell As Range
    Dim l_TargetCell As Range

    l_Row = Range(p_RangeFrom).Row
    l_Column = Range(p_RangeFrom).Column

    For Each thisCell In Range(p_RangeFrom)

        Set l_TargetCell = Range(Cells(thisCell.Row + p_OffsetRow, thisCell.Column + p_OffsetColumn).Address)

        ' Copy the text
        l_TargetCell.Value = thisCell.Value

        ' Copy the comment only if we have a comment to copy
        If Not thisCell.Comment Is Nothing Then

            ' Delete any existing comment in the target cell, if any.
            ' If you don't to this the .AddComment Method below will fail.
            If Not l_TargetCell.Comment Is Nothing Then l_TargetCell.Comment.Delete
            Call l_TargetCell.AddComment(thisCell.Comment.Text)

        End If

        ' Add more items to copy here, such as color, etc.

    Next

End Sub

Sub TestCall()
    Call CopySpecial("A1:B2", 3, 3)
End Sub
```